# Can't use bootstrap with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, css-loader

Using Express, Webpack and Bootstrap. I'm using `css-loader` for stylesheets.
Here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require("path");

config = {
    "entry": "./modules/entry.js",
    "output": {
        "path": path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
        "filename": "bundle.js"
    },
    "module": {
        "rules": [
            { "test": /\.css$/, "use": "css-loader"}
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = config
```

Entry.js only requires the stylesheets:

```
require("bootstrap")
require("glyphicons")
```

I put all these files in my public folder which I serve using `app.use(express.static("public"))`

And in my index.html I have a script tag:

```
<script src="./public/bundle.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Using bootstrap classes (or glyphicons) on my html does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for using bootstrap with webpack

https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader

Answer (score 1):

The `require('bootstrap')` will only import javascript in your case, to import CSS you need to use `require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')`, or in case of using non-compiled bootstrap version, you'll need more loaders.

You can find more info and configuration sample at official documentation page [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/)